# Scipy efficient sparse matrix construction

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I've been recently dealing with matrix constructnion in numpy/scipy, and I am trying to find an optimal solution to the following problem.

I have a function, which returns tuples, consisting of matrix row-indexes and the corresponding rows. At this moment, I simply construct a numpy matrix, such as:

```
mat = np.zeros((n, n))
```

where n is the matrix dimension. I incrementally loop through function results and add the corresponding rows to this very matrix in the following way:

```
mat[result_tuple[0],:] = result_tuple[1]
```

and it works fine and fast. The problem is, this is quite memory-intensive. Is there a way to do this efficiently with scipy.sparse module?

My current attempt works, but is quite slow:

```
for result_tuple in results:
    col    = range(0,n,1)
    row    = np.repeat(result_tuple[0],n)
    val    = result_tuple[1]
    mat = mat +  sp.csr_matrix((val, (row,col)), shape(n,n), dtype=float)
```

where again, result tuple consists of (row index, row data).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you collect all tuples at once (before sparse-mat creation)? If not, consider using some other sparse-mat build for incremental-construction: lil, dok or coo. 'Your approach seems to be hurt by [csr's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html): ```changes to the sparsity structure are expensive (consider LIL or DOK)```

Comment: Yes, this is also an option, I can pre-sort by index. I will also try with coo-s, thank you.

Comment: But the problem really is, that if I collect all the data before, I have not done anything, as memory footprint remains.

Comment: Why not? You don't collect a dense matrix, but sparse-indices (stored in some tuples)? Maybe improve your question a bit in this case. It's not very detailed.

Comment: I'm guessing that for a `n=5`, a tuple will look like `(0, [4,3,3,1,3])`.  That is, row number and a list with values for each column.  If so that is not suitable for sparse matrix construction (neither memory wise or speed).

Comment: What would then be the alternative for saving such matrix on the fly? HDF5?